# Improve Quality of H264 Deocder Media Foundation

Tags: uwp, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I am using MediaFoundation to read an MP4 video. My implementation is working fine and I can render the texture produced in DX. Below is the sample setup so it's clearer what I am doing.

```
ComPtr<IMFDXGIDeviceManager> manager;
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager(&resetToken, &manager));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(manager->ResetDevice(DxUtil::getDx11Device().Get(), resetToken));

mVideoAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_D3D_MANAGER, manager.Get());
mVideoAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_ADVANCED_VIDEO_PROCESSING, 1);
mVideoAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, 1);

std::wstring url = std::wstring(installedPath.begin(), installedPath.end()) + L"bbb.mp4";

DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(url.data(), mVideoAttributes.Get(), &mSourceReader));

DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(MFCreateMediaType(&mVideoMediaType));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(mVideoMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(mVideoMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_NV12));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(mSourceReader->SetCurrentMediaType(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, nullptr, mVideoMediaType.Get()));
```

The problem is, it's just not as sharp as the image compared to VLC Media player. My assumption is, although not sure, is that the decoder is set to default quality, not high. Is there any way to tell it to produce the best quality image?

Many thanks,
Peter

Comment: Decoders do not have quality. They should all decode exactly the same. Scalers do produce different qualitys  however.

Comment: Hmm ok. What is a scaler and how do I check to see if it's influencing the output? Never heard of one!